# Can't install OneNote on Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: installation, windows-7-x64, onenote

I'm try to install OneNote on a windows 7 64 bit pc and everytime i try to run the installer (Downloaded from here http://www.onenote.com/download) I get a   "microsoft office has stopped working" error message. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried asking the community on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/onenote-has-stopped-working-message-10-seconds/22d18d05-2c0c-4274-86f1-54c1f1f2c799) or some of the workarounds listed on the site?